# setInterval and clearInterval start when page load, and stop when leave page on ajax based site

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, setinterval, clearinterval

My current code. But when I load another page, timers does not stop. What I need is refreshing messages and dialogues when user is on the messages.php
My current code. But when I load another page, timers does not stop. What I need is refreshing messages and dialogues when user is on the messages.php
My current code. But when I load another page, timers does not stop. What I need is refreshing messages and dialogues when user is on the messages.php

```
    function get_page(link){
$jQuery("body").scrollTop(0);
$jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    async: false,
    url: link,
    data: "norefresh=1",
    success: function(data){
        window.history.pushState("", "", link);
        $jQuery("div.content").html(data);
        clearInterval(messagesref);
        clearInterval(dialoguesref);
        if(link.indexOf("messages.php")>=0){
            var messagesref = setInterval(function(){
                var link = window.location.href;
                var href = 'action/get'+link.substr(link.indexOf("messages.php"),30);
                var lmid = $jQuery('div.message').last().attr('id');
                $jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: href,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: 'lmid='+lmid,
                    success: function(response){
                        $jQuery.each(response, function(i,message) {
                            if(!$jQuery('#'+message.id).length){
                                if(message.from){var mside='right i';}else{var mside='left';};
                                $jQuery('div.messages').append('<div id="'+message.id+'" class="message '+mside+'" title="'+message.date+'">'+message.text+'</div>').scrollTop(10000);
                            };
                        });
                    }
                });
            },1000)

            var dialoguesref = setInterval(function(){
                var link = window.location.href;
                var link = link.replace("messages","action/getdialogues");
                $jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    cache: false,
                    async: false,
                    url: link,
                    data: 'q='+$jQuery('div.messages_users>input[type=text]').val(),
                    success: function(data){
                        $jQuery('div#dialogues').html(data);
                    },
                    error: function(data){
                    }
                });
            },5000)
        }
    }
});
```

};

Comment: Maybe this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active

Comment: Thank you, but my problem is when I go to for ex: profile.php the timer des not stop.

Comment: Have you tried to declare `messagesref` and `dialoguesref` outside the success callback? As each call to `success` will call its scoped variables

Comment: Yes, I have but it still does not stop